# change data number in Excel

Tags: excel

I know ms. excel since I was a kid, but I never tried to use function in excel before.

My table

```
    A             b
1 BirthDate Description
2       
3 440608        Alive
4 470330        Died
5 440401        Alive
6 450101        Died
```

I need to change the data in column birthdate which has description "died" so index number 3-4 in birthdate will be added by 1.

```
     A             b
  1 BirthDate   Description
  2     
  3 440608      Alive
  4 470430      Died
  5 440401      Alive
  6 450201      Died
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: by 1,index number 3-4 means index character in column A like 04 in the value (470430)

Answer (score 0):

If sorting is allowed OP has not answered that request for clarification) then sort to gather the `Died` together, enter `100` in some cell and copy it, select ColumnA where ColumnB has `Died` and Paste Special with Operation Add, OK.